# Is "It's a way to find your way through the city" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

> It's a way to find your way through this city.

Is this sentence grammatically correct, and why or why not?

Comment: It doesn't read well, but I don't see anything grammatically incorrect about it.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is not a proofreading service; please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of the kinds of questions we can answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically no problem, but the doubling "way"s are annoying, isn't it.
I would say "It's a way to navigate the city".

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer is fine, but please consider editing out the question at the end. This site is intended for questions and answers, not conversation.